# Retrieving time rows by conditions. Get code worked within one day period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the events. The basic example can be reproduced by the code:

```
data = [['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'AC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'], ['2019-01-11 16:27:39', 'DC', '2019-01-11 16:54:53'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:00:25'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'DC', '2019-01-14 09:58:39'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:42', 'Battery', '2019-01-14 10:00:48'], ['2019-01-11 17:03:48', 'Cell', '2019-01-12 17:26:48'], ['2019-01-14 10:00:36', 'DC', '2019-01-14 10:33:42'], ['2019-01-14 10:32:42', 'AC', '2019-01-14 10:45:27']]  

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start', 'Alarm', 'End'])  
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

My general goal is to monitor occurred alarms. Alarms like DC/Battery/Cell usually occur with the AC at the same time or later.

So I want to add the column 'AC Start' which will be filled with the timestamp of the correspondent AC alarm associated with other alarms and then calculate time difference between the AC alarm occurrence and occurrence of other alarms.

This is my code to do it:

```
ac_mask = df.Alarm.eq('AC')
df['AC Start'] = df.Start.where(ac_mask).ffill().mask(ac_mask)
df['AC End'] = df.End.where(ac_mask).ffill().mask(ac_mask)
df['Time between events'] = (df['Start'] - df['AC Start']).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

It worked great until I faced the situation when alarm occurred earlier than right AC and was wrong associated. (See the photo) [image]

So my question is how can I tune code to work only within one day period to look for matchings?

Comment: Get the current day, then have an if statement that only lets in days that are + or - 1, unless day == 1 or day == 28, 29, 30, 31, etc. You will need more code for determining the month, so you know what the last day is, but you get the idea.

Comment: You may try to put pd.Timestamp inside your cells, instead of putting string. Storing string in columns may cause bulk operations to give wrong results. When I tried your code above last line is not working in Python 3.7.

Comment: @furkanayd thatks for admitting, I forgot to add rows for converting the example df's time columns to datetime format. The original df is timestamped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some additional filtering on your `ac_mask` and change the way you create `AC Start` and `AC End` a little:

```
# 1. Change condition to ne('AC') instead of eq('AC')
# 2. Add conditional that Start must be on the same date, backfilled NA values

ac_mask = df.Alarm.ne('AC') & df.Start.dt.date.eq(df.Start.shift().bfill().dt.date)
```

Let's take a look at how the mask looks like now:

```
>>> df['ac_mask'] = ac_mask
>>> df[['Start', 'Alarm', 'ac_mask']]
                Start    Alarm  ac_mask
0 2019-01-11 16:27:39       AC    False
1 2019-01-11 16:27:39       DC     True
2 2019-01-11 17:03:42       AC    False
3 2019-01-11 17:03:42       DC     True
4 2019-01-11 17:03:42  Battery     True
5 2019-01-11 17:03:48     Cell     True
6 2019-01-14 10:00:36       DC    False   # <-- Alarm on different date is no longer captured
7 2019-01-14 10:32:42       AC    False
```

Now also adjust how you mask the `AC Start` and `AC End`:

```
df['AC Start'] = df.Start.mask(ac_mask).ffill().where(ac_mask)
df['AC End'] = df.End.mask(ac_mask).ffill().where(ac_mask)
```

The rest is just the same:

```
df['Time between events'] = (df['Start'] - df['AC Start']).dt.total_seconds()/60  

>>> df
                Start    Alarm                 End            AC Start              AC End  Time between events  
0 2019-01-11 16:27:39       AC 2019-01-11 16:54:53                 NaT                 NaT                  NaN     
1 2019-01-11 16:27:39       DC 2019-01-11 16:54:53 2019-01-11 16:27:39 2019-01-11 16:54:53                  0.0  
2 2019-01-11 17:03:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:00:25                 NaT                 NaT                  NaN  
3 2019-01-11 17:03:42       DC 2019-01-14 09:58:39 2019-01-11 17:03:42 2019-01-14 10:00:25                  0.0  
4 2019-01-11 17:03:42  Battery 2019-01-14 10:00:48 2019-01-11 17:03:42 2019-01-14 10:00:25                  0.0  
5 2019-01-11 17:03:48     Cell 2019-01-12 17:26:48 2019-01-11 17:03:42 2019-01-14 10:00:25                  6.0  
6 2019-01-14 10:00:36       DC 2019-01-14 10:33:42                 NaT                 NaT                  NaN  
7 2019-01-14 10:32:42       AC 2019-01-14 10:45:27                 NaT                 NaT                  NaN
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with loop, but sure there must be a more elegant way. So the question is still opened.

```
as_start = tr[tr['Alarm']=='AC']['Start'].dt.date.unique()  

dt = pd.DataFrame([])
for date in as_start:
    tt = tr[tr['Start'].dt.date==date]
    ac_mask = tt.Alarm.eq('AC')
    tt['AC Start'] = tt.Start.where(ac_mask).ffill().mask(ac_mask) 
    tt['AC End'] = tt.End.where(ac_mask).ffill().mask(ac_mask)
    tt['Time between events'] = (tt['Start'] - tt['AC Start']).dt.total_seconds()/60
    dt = dt.append(tt)
```